# Format number with locale specific settings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that JS or jQuery formats my number by locale.

So for example number 999666555444333.22

might be as

```
999'666'555'444'333.22
```

or

```
999.666.555.444.333,22
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The globalize plugin will do the trick for you

https://github.com/jquery/globalize